# End Of CSS Sprite Button Dropping Off Inside Table

Tags: css, button, sprite

I'm creating a CSS button and it is working ALMOST perfectly.  The problem is that when the button is larger than its allotted space, its end drops off to the next line.  It also extends the page width to fit it properly, but then the end is on the next line >=(.  Extending the page is perfectly fine, but the button should be whole.

Here is my example page...
http://www.lolstrategies.com/test/button_sample.html

It uses two tables and the button needs to also be in a table.

My current css uses float: left to push the images together as you can see by viewing the source.  I'm hoping that it doesn't all need to be completely redone without float but I am willing to do so if that's the only answer.

The image I'm using is this:

[image]

Comment: From my understanding, if you put text inside an HTML element without any kind of formatting (such as spaces) then it's going to extend out of the element width unless specified otherwise via overflow:hidden; - The reason for this is a bit unclear to me but it seems to work this way.

Comment: I'm afraid that "float:left" will always do this when there's not enough space for the second element. You have to either give it more space, or use another approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to completely redo it. Just a couple of small changes. Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/tw16/Pwmcn/

```
.buttonLarge {
    height:22px;
    margin: 0 22px 0 12px; /* add this */
}
.primaryLargeButtonEnd {
    width: 12px;
    height:12px;  
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 5px;
    display: inline-block; /* add this instead of float:left */
    background: transparent url('./composite__V153767378_.png') no-repeat left -75px;
}
```

Comment: That definitely does the trick in Firefox... However when using IE it looks pretty destroyed.  I looked at your live example in IE and it looked good, I'm guessing js-fiddle's renderer is more Firefox than IE.  I updated my example ( http://www.lolstrategies.com/test/button_sample.html ) to use your version so you can see how it looks in IE.  Thanks for the help!  Any ideas on fixing IE?

Comment: @user379467: The reason it looks messed up in IE when you apply it to your example, is because you haven't applied a doctype. This means IE goes into quirks mode. If you put `<!DOCTYPE html>` as the very first thing in your document (even before `<html>` tag) it will look good again and make sure IE goes into standards mode instead.